# "Yourapp" has not been registered - expo

Tags: react-native, expo

My app works on expo with no error.

But when I try to work it with my xcode, It returns error like below.
And when I publish application, It crashes when I click.

Whats wrong with it?

I searched on google, and tried everything I found. But nothing solved my problem.
Actually, I couldn't even understand the problem.

Here's my /index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo'
import App from './src/App'

registerRootComponent(App)
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "app2021",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@freakycoder/react-native-bounceable": "^0.2.4",
    "@paraboly/react-native-card": "github:Paraboly/react-native-card#expo",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.5",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.0.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.3",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-daterange-picker": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.64.0",
    "react-native-floating-label-input": "^1.2.16",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-flipper": "^1.4.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "victory": "^35.4.3",
    "victory-native": "^35.3.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "timers": "fake",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
}
```

Sharing error below:
has not been registered. This can happen if:

```
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called
```

Comment: you can give more information

Comment: What steps did you follow to build the app ?

Comment: I open the xcode, pick the "ios 11" from the list. and click on play button.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me with android. IOS might have a similar problem.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.